# Glassfish 3.1 JMS Queue Monitoring and Statistics

Tags: jms, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I come from the world of Tibco and EMS (the same as JMS) and I was wondering if there is a GUI way to see statistics of the JMS queues in Glassfish.

For example, I would like to know how many messages were published, how many consumed, durable connections, active subscribers and publishers, things like that.

I have seen that previous versions seemed to have it, but in the administration manual of Glassfish I can't find any other way than using the console. I think this is kind or archaic.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glassfish uses "Open Message Queue" and it comes with a GUI admin tool plus a full suite of command line tools. You can find these in the Glassfish/imq/bin folder. The gui tool is imqadmin which will answer some of the questions you asked.

You can also use a 3rd party app if you wanted as well, you just need to supply the connection info.

Visit the [Oracle GlassFish Server Message Queue 4.5 Administration Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2438/index.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you man, this worked, didn't know that. Although is still really bad compared to Tibco :S